# Determine process which uses the max amount of memory (RAM)?

Tags: linux, unix, process

I've little question about linux process administration:

How I can determine process (PID) which uses the max amount of memory (RAM) in system?

I google about this problem and do not find a usefull solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by memory you mean resident set size (RSS)

```
ps axh -o pid --sort -rss | head -n 1
```

Comment: Ok. How option(s) can i add to this command to see memory information for selection process PID?

Comment: Change the `-o` specification (see the manpage), e.g. to show the actual memory usage as well use `-o pid,rss`.

Comment: Thank for help Lars. This solution is work fine.